# Handle colon in filename with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

When I try to make a thumbnail from a pdf file, using:

```
convert -density 200 -quality 100 path/to/some:file.pdf[0] thumb.jpeg
```

I get this error:

```
convert: unable to open image `file.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
convert: no images defined `test.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

I think the colon in the filename is the problem here. I tried escaping it, and enclosing the filename in double quote, but no luck... Is it even possible to use this command with such filenames?

Comment: You could try enclosing your filename and path in double quotation marks "path/to/some:file.pdf[0]"

Comment: Already tried it... I have updated my question

Comment: **ImageMagick** uses a string followed by a colon to specify a file type where it cannot be determined from the extension e.g. `convert xc:blue GIF:a` and Windows uses it for drive separator, so I would suggest avoiding it. If you have to use it, I can only suggest you make a symlink to it e.g. `ln -s some:file.pdf sensible.pdf`. I note that `convert some:file.pdf something.jpg` does work, just not with `[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle colons in the filename, prefix it with a colon:

```
convert -density 200 -quality 100 :path/to/some:file.pdf[0] thumb.jpeg
```